# Spring bean for AWS IoT Core using default credential provider chain

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-iot

I am trying to create Spring Bean for different aws resources using default credential provider chain concept.
I can able to build bean for resources like sqs, s3 etc. but couldnot able find a way to create the same for iot core.

```
@Bean
public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
 AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync = 
 AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
 return amazonSQSAsync;
}
```

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 getS3Config() {
 AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
 return s3Client;
}
```

I want something like this for creating bean for aws iot core(AWSIotMqttClient).
I am using below dependency for iot core.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.11</version>
</dependency>
```